# Create a url with a route/waypoint

Tags: java, google-maps

I have a java application which connects to a GPS,and intermittently save the geolocation. And based on a list of GPS coordinates(lat/long), I want to create a google maps URL/link with all the coordinates. This URL will then be added to a email and forwarded to the users email account.

I can create a static map like this, 
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:1|56.1721,10.1811&markers=color:blue|label:2|56.1721,10.1711&markers=color:blue|label:3|56.1721,10.1611&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel:1%7C56.1721,10.1811&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel:2%7C56.1721,10.1711&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel:3%7C56.1721,10.1611&sensor=false)
but if there is more than 40 or so waypoints, then url becomes to long and I get a HTTP error 414

I would like to create a link to dynamic google map, and have the link hold about 100 waypoints as a maximum.

Any google maps experts out there??

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485888/google-static-map-api-long-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163652/google-maps-and-a-lot-of-path-points-long-polyline

Comment: This link (provided by @grams)did the trick [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485888/google-static-map-api-long-url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485888/google-static-map-api-long-url